# How to take weighted sums of each row of a matrix in R

Tags: r, portfolio

I have a weighted portfolio of stocks and a history of their daily returns.  I'm trying to compute the return of the portfolio on each of the historic days assuming the weights don't move, and replacing missing data with zeroes (I'm trying to compute historic *VaR*, or *Value at Risk*).

Here is a simplified version:

```
# portfolio
pfolio = data.frame(ticker = c("stock_a", "stock_b", "stock_noob"), weight = c(0.25, 0.6, 0.15))

# Daily stock returns (with some NA values for one stock):
m = matrix(c(0.0016, 0.0037, -0.0042, -0.0096, -0.0006, -0.0043, -0.0292, -0.0158, 0.0128, 0.0113, 0.0016, 0.0042, NA, NA, 0.0168, -0.0293, 0.0037, -0.0083),
    nrow = 6,
    ncol = 3,
    dimnames = list(c("2017-03-01", "2017-03-02", "2017-03-03", "2017-03-06", "2017-03-07", "2017-03-08"), c("stock_a", "stock_b", "stock_noob"))
)
```

I'm trying to use a clever `apply` or `mapply` method, but the best I can come up with is cleaning the data first, then applying a for-loop (yuck):

```
m_clean = apply(m, c(1, 2), function(x) if (is.na(x)) 0 else x)
answer = numeric(0)
for (i in 1:nrow(m_clean)) {
    answer = c(answer, sum(m_clean[i, pfolio$ticker] * pfolio$weight))
}
```

So the main question is:  what is a clean, one-line way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
m_clean <- ifelse(is.na(m), 0, m) # or 
m_clean <- m; m_clean[is.na(m_clean)] <- 0
```

and then

```
answer <- apply(m_clean, 1, weighted.mean, w=pfolio$weight) # or
answer <- colSums(t(m_clean) * pfolio$weight) # or
answer <- tcrossprod(pfolio$weight, m_clean)
```

The last is giving a matrix:

```
#> tcrossprod(pfolio$weight, m_clean)
#     2017-03-01 2017-03-02 2017-03-03 2017-03-06 2017-03-07 2017-03-08
#[1,]   -0.01712  -0.008555    0.00915   -1.5e-05   0.001365      2e-04
```

the other solutions are giving a named vector.

#### benchmarks:

```
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(
  a= apply(m_clean, 1, weighted.mean, w=pfolio$weight),
  c= colSums(t(m_clean) * pfolio$weight),
  p= tcrossprod(pfolio$weight, m_clean),
  m= m_clean %*% pfolio$weight
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
#    a 49.115 51.0590 54.46379 52.3685 53.9815 99.023   100   c
#    c 12.688 13.8385 15.02912 14.8460 15.7560 32.366   100  b 
#    p  5.978  6.8955  7.75998  7.4170  7.8770 30.771   100 a  
#    m  5.438  6.4330  6.95056  6.8615  7.2710 17.109   100 a
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for teaching me about the `microbenchmark` package.  The tcrossprod will give a vector instead of a matrix if you reverse the two parameters:  `tcrossprod(m_clean, pfolio$weight)`, as you did in the microbenchmark example.